# When @material-ui/core will be deprecated?

Tags: material-ui

Now that v5 is released and it's moving away from JSS, I am interested in knowing how long will the v4 will last, so I can start to plan a migration time ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Long-term support (LTS)**
> MUI will continue to provide security updates and support for regressions for one version prior to the current major version, for example regressions caused by external factors such as browser updates, or changes to upstream dependencies.

The last version right now is v5.

> So, the "Only handle security fixes." policy (which is also about upstream regressions, e.g. Chrome that adds a regression, yes it has happened) **will be until v6 is released (likely in 2023,** and with fewer BCs).

[reference1](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30778)
[reference2](https://mui.com/versions/#supported-versions)